# Analyzing the number in xslt

Tags: xslt

Logic :

- When combining the `<lpage>` content with the `<fpage>` content to generate the content for the CXML, only the differing numbers should be included. For example, in the code sample, the `<fpage>` element is `1545` and the `<lpage>` element is `1547`, making only the final digit (7) different, so the resulting content should be `1545–7`. However, if the `<lpage>` content was `1557`, then the result would be `1545–57`.

Input :

```
<doc>
  <year>2007</year>;
  <volume>26</volume>:
  <fpage>1545</fpage>-
  <lpage>1547</lpage>
</doc>
```

Output should be :

```
<p>2007;26(6):1545-7.</p
```

I have no idea to compare those numbers and getting the desired output.

Comment: Does your processor support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: @michael.hor257k. I am using XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible solutions, using **XSLT 2.0**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:my="dummy" exclude-result-prefixes="my xs">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:function name="my:lastPage">
    <xsl:param name="s1" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="s2" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:variable name="l1" select="string-length($s1)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="l2" select="string-length($s2)"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to $l2">
      <xsl:if test="$l1 lt $l2 or substring($s1, 1, .) != substring($s2, 1, .)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($s2, ., 1)"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="doc">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="concat(year, ';', volume, '(6):', fpage, '-')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="my:lastPage(fpage, lpage)"/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The main part of this solution is a function (*lastPage*), with 2 arguments
(*fpage* and *lpage*).
It loops over chars in *lpage* and includes the current char in the result
if:

- either *fpage* is shorter than *lpage* (e.g. *100* and *1000*),
- or the substring of *lpage* up to the current char is different than
  the corresponding substring of *fpage*.

Comment: This is a good start - but it fails when the range is 100 - 1000.

Comment: *Michael*, thanks for observance. I corrected the script to provide proper reaction in the case you pointed out.

Comment: @Valdi_Bo When i am running above code I am getting `<p>2007;26(6):1545-1547</p>` as the results. Actually I want `<p>2007;26(6):1545-47</p>` as the result

Comment: The expression in the `xsl:if` in the function should use `lt` rather than `le` I think....

Comment: @TimC yeah It is correct. when I am using `lt`, this works perfectly

Comment: Of course, if *fpage* is **shorter** than *lpage* then there should be **lt** (my mistake, I corrected it).

Answer (score 0):

**Please Use This Code**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="fpagelenght" select="string-length(doc/fpage)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="lpagelenght" select="string-length(doc/lpage)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vollenght" select="string-length(doc/volume)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="match1" select="number(substring(doc/fpage, 1, 1))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="match2" select="number(substring(doc/lpage, 1, 1))"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="doc">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="year | fpage">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="volume">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:if test="$vollenght &gt; 1">
            <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(., $vollenght)"/>
            <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="lpage">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$match2 = $match1">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$lpagelenght = 2 and $fpagelenght = 2">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., $lpagelenght - 1)"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$lpagelenght = 3 and $fpagelenght = 3">
                        <xsl:value-of select="number(substring(., $lpagelenght - 1))"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$lpagelenght = 4 and $fpagelenght = 4">
                        <xsl:value-of select="number(substring(., $lpagelenght - 1))"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```